# Twitter Bootstrap Nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

http://www.ontargettdesign.com

Hi,

I am having problem with the navigation bar and the logo when the webpage is resized to ipad size:

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/4r95qo.png[/IMG]

How can I code it to be a narrower height, I feel I have tried everything!

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the logo to be smaller or to have the logo not be clipped? Right now the logo is clipped because of the width and height. Do you want the logo to show at size but not clipped?

Answer (score 1):

Your Media Queries are clipping the image. This is because the div you have is smaller than the background image being used. **If you remove the "width" & height"** the logo will display properly. **To view this**. Make you browser smaller to see the clipping occur (Because of @media). Right click on the logo and "inspect element". On the right or bottom it will show you the css that is applied to this image. You can toggle the css to see how the code effects your image.

either add **background-size:contain;** to both of the follow or remove the width and height.

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 769px)
.navbar-brand {
    height: 32px;
    width: 132px;
}
```

&

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
.navbar-brand {
    height: 32px;
    width: 132px;
}
```

**To change make the navbar height** the same across all media widths you will still have to mess with the media widths. Your standard height is "height: 76px;".

The first CSS is for the smallest possible screen

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
.navbar {
   height: 76px; /* add this */
}
```

This is the second smallest screen (for tablets). You will not to get rid of the clear:both that is sending the navigation to the second line

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 769px)
.navbar-collapse {
   float: none;
   clear: both; /* DELETE THIS */
   height: 100px; /* You can change this to 76px if you want to be consistent */
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry I haven't explained this very well, I am having a problem with the height of the grey strip, I want it the same width as when it is on a full size browser. Hope this makes sense, my fault not explaining that the problem was the height of the grey "banner" and not the logo

Comment: I left my original answer because it is something that you should look at to fix the logo on different displays. I add how to change the nav height on different screen widths. You will still have to mess around with some formatting (adding margins and paddings).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for your help, the clear: both fixed this. Appreciate your help.

Would you be able to tell me why this gave me the desired result? I like to try and understand what went wrong, so I can avoid the mistake in the future.

Comment: The navigation was floating right of the logo. When the navigation hits the logo at that width (because of the media query)it was clearing both floats and moving down. Removing that code keeps the navigation bar floating right of he logo.